# Errors while installing VS2015 tools for .NET Core 1.0 development

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2015

I have difficulties updating my development machine to use the newest Visual Studio tools to support my development.

I did the following (VS2015 means Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition):

1. Uninstall my previous version of VS2015 Update 1. I should mention that I have installed various stuff on top of this such as AspNet5.ENU.RC1_Update1_KB3137909.exe and VWDOrVs2015AzurePack.exe (VS tools for Azure).
2. Restart
3. Install VS2015 using this file vs_community__55e913f53149d443afc7d14b09172fd9.exe. This ended with minor errors such as

   [0EE0:0E48][2016-08-10T11:42:51]i301: Applying execute package: MobileServicesConnectedServices_VS, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{A4495E4F-5218-48FB-8AD2-F3076011B9E1}v14.0.23107\packages\MobileServicesConnectedServices\MobileServicesConnectedServices_VisualStudio14.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"' [16DC:16E0][2016-08-10T11:42:58]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (MobileServicesConnectedServices_VS) failed: Error Message Id: 1722 ErrorMessage: There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.
   [0EE0:0E48][2016-08-10T11:42:58]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.

and

```
[0EE0:0E48][2016-08-10T11:42:45]i301: Applying execute package: AuthenticationConnectedServices_VS, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{3FEAC561-1CF6-41D6-B0F3-BECDD9C88A1B}v14.0.23107\packages\AuthenticationConnectedServices\AuthenticationConnectedServices_VisualStudio14.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"' [16DC:16E0][2016-08-10T11:42:50]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (AuthenticationConnectedServices_VS) failed: Error Message Id: 1722 ErrorMessage: There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  
[0EE0:0E48][2016-08-10T11:42:51]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
```

4. Restart

Now, if I try to install the VS2015 Tools Preview from a file called DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe I get this error:

```
Setup has detected that Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 may not be completely installed. Please repair Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, then install this product again.
```

and when I open the log file I see this:

```
[1B14:1A6C][2016-08-10T12:58:43]e000: Error 0x81f40001: Bundle condition evaluated to false: WixBundleInstalled OR NOT(((VS2015CommunityUpdateVersion <> VS2015UpdateVersion) AND (VS2015CommunityExists) AND (VS2015UpdateVersionExists)) OR ((VS2015ProfessionalUpdateVersion <> VS2015UpdateVersion) AND (VS2015ProfessionalExists) AND (VS2015UpdateVersionExists)) OR ((VS2015EnterpriseUpdateVersion <> VS2015UpdateVersion) AND (VS2015EnterpriseExists) AND (VS2015UpdateVersionExists)) OR ((VS2015WebExpressUpdateVersion <> VS2015UpdateVersion) AND (VS2015WebExpressExists) AND (VS2015UpdateVersionExists))) OR (SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1) OR (WixBundleAction=2)
```

I am now trying to install from scratch using a fresh Windows 10 installation to avoid problems related to side-effects from earlier installations.

I'm curious though to find out, what might cause these problems, and find out if I am doing something wrong.

Edit 2016-08-10: I have now verified that the same error occurs on a freshly installed Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after some more digging. It turns out many people faced this problem as described here: 
 (Click the Reviews tab):

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c94a02e9-f2e9-4bad-a952-a63a967e3935

After trying this from a command prompt:

```
DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1
```

the installation continues.

Answer (score 1):

Above didn't work for me, nor did several other solutions I found online, but this finally worked:

1. Go to extensions folder, e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
   Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions
2. There will be a lot of cryptically named folders, e.g. "kehkjkd2.pme"
3. Open each folder to see if it is a nuget extension folder (if it contains ~40 files named nuget.*.dll)
4. If it is a nuget extension folder, delete it or move it to a backup folder.
5. Repeat - there may be multiple folders containing nuget.

After doing the above and rebooting (not sure if the reboot is necessary), the .NET Core 1.0.0 VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2 install worked.